# memory gets overwritten mips

Tags: memory, mips

I'm having a problem with some MIPS code where the first 2 elements of an array get overwritten.  I'm accepting 4 different inputs from the user, each one byte, and then storing them in a '.space' of size 4.  When I print them all, The first 2 elements are blank.  I'm figuring this has something to do with a carriage return, but I'm not entirely sure.  Here's what I'm working with:

```
    .data
msg:        .asciiz "Enter the band colors\n"
band12:     .asciiz "Value bands (first 2 band colors)\n"
bandM:      .asciiz "Multiplier band\n"
bandT:      .asciiz "Tolerance band\n"
buffer:     .byte '0'
userInput:  .space 4
normalized: .word 0
tolerance:  .ascii ""

    .text
main:   li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, msg
    syscall

    la $a0, band12
    syscall

    la $t0, userInput #store the input array in a register

    li $v0, 8 #read the first input into buffer
    la $a0, buffer
    la $a1, 8
    syscall

    #store the input into the first element of the input array
    lb $t1, buffer 
    sb $t1, ($t0)

    #read the second input into buffer
    la $a0, buffer
    la $a1, 8
    syscall

    lb $t2, buffer #store the input into the second element of the input array
    sb $t2, 1($t0)

    #3rd band message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, bandM
    syscall

    #read in 3rd band
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    la $a1, 8
    syscall

    #move to 3rd array index
    lb $t3, buffer
    sb $t3, 2($t0)

    #last prompt
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, bandT
    syscall

    #read tolerance band
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    la $a1, 8
    syscall

    #move to 4th array index
    lb $t4, buffer
    sb $t4, 3($t0)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, ($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 1($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 2($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 3($t0)
    syscall

    jr $ra

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

This is the output from QtSpim.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using spim:

The `$a1` argument for `syscall 8` is the number of characters to be read. Your code sets `$a1` to 8 allowing up to 9 bytes to be read, but your buffer is only a single byte. The buffer might also need to be aligned to a 32 bit boundary, using `.align 2`.

Comment: Played around for a bit and this is basically the reason.  I switched the syscall to 12 to read a byte and that fixed it.  The \n\0 from syscall 8 was overwriting the parts of the array that I needed.